# use findall() method to parse a simple math equations

Tags: python, regex

how to use findall() method to parse a math equation?

for example, if I have an equation 8x >= 4 + 2y + 10z

here is my coding

```
import re
equations = '8x >= 4 + 2y + 10z'
regexparse = r'\w+|[+/*-]'
result = re.findall(regexparse, equations)
print(result)
```

the output is

```
['8x', '4', '+', '2y', '+', '10z']
```

instead, I expect this result:

```
[('','8','x','>='),('','4','',''),('+','2','y',''),('+','10','z','')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 4 capture groups instead if you want `re.findall` to return a list of 4-tuples:

```
result = re.findall(r'(?=\S)([-+*/])?\s*(\d+)?\s*([a-z]+)?\s*([<>]?=)?', equations)
```

Given your sample input of `equations = '8x >= 4 + 2y + 10z'`, `result` would become:

```
[('', '8', 'x', '>='), ('', '4', '', ''), ('+', '2', 'y', ''), ('+', '10', 'z', '')]
```